# reporting services (ssrs) prompts with username/password

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using reporting services 2010 and get the following prompt when trying to access the reports:

[image]

In the reports definition, I have specified the database username/password.

Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: This is authentication to get to the report server, for a different authentication scheme follow the guidelines outlined by MS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253.aspx

Comment: I'm using SSRS 2016 and was able to get the authentication dialog to go away by 1.) following the instructions on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/reporting-services-login-dialog-box-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017  and 2.) opening the report solution and deploying all reports. After doing those two things, the reports loaded without the username/password dialog box.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are actually two logins you deal with when it comes to reporting services.

1. The login to the database is to capture the data, it has
   nothing to do with the actual report itself.  That login you used is
   sent to the database as the user / credentials being used to pull
   the report data.
2. This prompt you have a screen shot of, is the authentication to the report server, by      default rs uses windows authentication so enter your domain\username with
   password.

If you do not like this default behavior you can change it, this guide should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253.aspx

See this as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx

Comment: is it possible to input that prompt with a default username/password?

Comment: You will need to edit the reporting services web config files and use some sort of impersonation, check out the link I posted.  However, just a note, to me this will appear one account is accessing any report at any given time.  This might be okay for you, if that is the case proceed, but if you plan to take advantage of the reporting service database for statistics / metrics you will no longer get a listing of say all the users who ran a report.

Answer (score 2):

Open your project/Solution in SSRS tool. Select the report properties (Right click on report project and select properties). Update 'Overwrite dataset' and 'Overwrite datasource' as True.
 Then go to your shared Datasource properties and select 'credentials' section. There you can select 'Use this username and password' option and set appropriate SQL Server credentials. Click ok and no more Prompting for credentials from frond end :)

Comment: I disagree with this answer b/c of the point made in the comment by JonH

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to by pass the login prompt, you can modify the 'TargetServerURL' as it includes 'reportserver'. (It is like suffixing Controller with controller name in MVC)

Environment: Visual Studio 2008, Sql Server 2008

For me, it prompted when I set the 'TargetServerURL' to localhost/finreport. As mentioned in the below article, changing the 'TargetServerURL' to localhost/reportserver bypassed the login prompt.

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/reporting-services-login-dialog-box-ssrs

Answer (score 1):

My case was because I was using ReportViewer version 10 for accessing a Report Server 2014. Upgrading the ReportViewer to version 11 eliminates this problem.

Check your Web.config for \configuration\system.webServer\handlers\add[type].

Answer (score 1):

The previous select solution could not work for someone (It didn't for me), so I will show you how can you bypass it. SSRS used internet explorer to run those requests in the background (even if you use other browsers), so the solution will be adding a different type of Authentication to IE. Go to:

Open Internet Explore -> Internet Options -> Custom -> user authentication select
"Automatic logon with current user name and password"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to your web portal url->site setting->security->add user or group, do it to all the items you want to upload as well.