# Report Manager 2008 r2 - prompts for username/password

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to solve this issue from past 2 days with no luck.

I tried using suggestions from many blogs related to this topic, with settings related to network users and changing config values under "AuthenticationTypes".

Can any one point me to new road to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166202/reporting-services-ssrs-prompts-with-username-password

Comment: I checked the above link , Its not working. @ whereisSQL.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to list out the things you tried? That way, it might help with eliminating some possible solutions that you might have already tested

Comment: We Removed RSWindowsNegotiate and ensure RSWindowsNTLM is specified in the file rsreportserver.config

2) OR, change the report server service account to Network Service