# Reporting Services prompts for Credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reporting-services-2012

I have an Iframe through which I will call the reporting service

`<iframe src="@(ViewBag.ReportUrl)" id="ifReport" scrolling="yes" height="500" width="100%"></iframe>`

each time I try to call this service it is asking for credentials

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this prompt. My web applications use Active Directory Credentials for login, So the same credentials are used here. Can I use that credentials while calling this service to avoid the prompt? I have already referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166240/10325225 . But that answer got me nowhere

```
<AuthenticationTypes>
            <RSWindowsNTLM/>
        </AuthenticationTypes>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
        <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
        <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
    </Authentication>
```

these are authentication provided in the RSReportServer.config. I know that there is a way to implement custom Authentication. Apart from that is there any method for a single time sign in

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. To view a report in an `iframe`, you must first make a small ASP.NET Web Forms project with a page with a `ReportViewer` control inside:

```
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
       <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" >
       </rsweb:ReportViewer>
 </form>

ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
CustomReportCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(userName,password, domain); // if you dont have a domain enter computer name
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = host/reportServer not portal;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = important! <report path with folder that contains report.rdl>;
```

After that, put in the `iframe`'s `src` URL to the webform project; e.g.,

```
localhost/ReportPage.aspx
```

You can find an example of `class CustomReportCredentials :IReportServerCredentials` if you search on Google.

Comment: Can you link to an example of such an implementation, instead of just directing readers to search on Google?

Answer (score 0):

In ReportPage.aspx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

  <form id="CommonReport" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form>
```

In ReportPage.aspx.cs

```
namespace ReportWebForm
{
     public partial class ReportPage:SystemWeb.Ui.Page
         {
             if(!IsPostBack)
             {
               CustomReportCredentials  irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(userName, password,domain) //if you dont have domain enter computer name
             ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
             ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
         ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://<ssrs ip>/ReportServer"); 
             ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "ReportFolder/Report1";
             }
         }

      [Serializable]
      public class CustomReportCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
        {
            private string reportServerUserName;
            private string reportServerPassword;
            private string reportServerDomain;
    
            public CustomReportCredentials(string userName, string password, string domain)
            {
                reportServerUserName = userName;
                reportServerPassword = password;
                reportServerDomain = domain;
            }
            public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
            {
                get
                {
                    // Use default identity.
                    return null;
                }
            }
    
            public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
            {
                get
                {
                    // Use default identity.
                    return new NetworkCredential(reportServerUserName, reportServerPassword, reportServerDomain);
                }
            }
            public void New(string userName, string password, string domain)
            {
                reportServerUserName = userName;
                reportServerPassword = password;
                reportServerDomain = domain;
            }
    
            public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string user, out string password, out string authority)
            {
                // Do not use forms credentials to authenticate.
                authCookie = null;
                user = null;
                password = null;
                authority = null;
    
                return false;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).